flutter local notification handle notification click
I am using the following code to receive notifications in Flutter via Firebase and the flutter_local_notifications package:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await setupNotification();
  await setupFirebase();
}

var hasNotifAction = false;
var payload = null;

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
  android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
);

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
setupNotification() async {
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: handleOnClick,
    onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: handleOnClickBackground
  );
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
handleOnClick(NotificationResponse response) {
  hasNotifAction = true;
  payload = jsonDecode(response.payload!);
  handleNotificationAction();
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
handleOnClickBackground(NotificationResponse response) {
  print('00000000000000000000000000000000000');
  print(response);
  print('00000000000000000000000000000000001');

  hasNotifAction = true;
  payload = jsonDecode(response.payload!);
}

setupFirebase() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((event) {
    hasNotifAction = true;

  },);

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseBackgroundMessage);

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
    showNotification(message);
  });
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
    showNotification(message);
}

Future<void> showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
  int id = Random().nextInt(100);

  var bigPictureStyleInformation = null;

  if (message.data['banner'] != 'noimage.png') {
    final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(uploadFilePath + message.data['banner']));
    bigPictureStyleInformation = BigPictureStyleInformation(
      ByteArrayAndroidBitmap.fromBase64String(base64Encode(response.bodyBytes)),
    );
  }

  AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
      AndroidNotificationDetails(id.toString(), 'basic',
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          styleInformation: bigPictureStyleInformation,
          ticker: 'ticker');

  NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
      NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

  String payload = jsonEncode(message.data);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      id, message.data['title'] ?? '', message.data['body'] ?? '', platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: payload);
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
handleNotificationAction() async {
  if (hasNotifAction) {
    hasNotifAction = false;
    if (payload['action'] == 'link') {
      launchUrl(Uri.parse(payload['actionContent']), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
    }
    if (payload['action'] == 'music') {
      var music = await Get.find<MusicsController>().getMusic(Get.overlayContext!, id: payload['actionContent']);
      Get.to(MusicPlayerScreen(musicModel: music, playlist: [],));
    }
    if (payload['action'] == 'artist') {
      var artist = await Get.find<ArtistsController>().getArtist(Get.overlayContext!, int.parse(payload['actionContent']));
      Get.to(ArtistDetailScreen(artistModel: artist));
    }
  }
}


Android Manifest:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <!-- ALSO ADD THIS PERMISSION IF TARGETING SDK 34 -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:label="Avaz"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="basic" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="avaz" android:host="open.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.receivers.NotificationReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.receivers.ActionReceiver" />

        <!-- ADD THIS "SERVICE" element -->
        <service
            android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!-- ADD THIS "RECEIVER" element -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
    </application>
    
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>


The problem is that when the application is closed, I receive the notification and clicking on it opens the application, but the handleOnClickBackground function never gets executed.
